# Building a symmetric matrix in Python from data in file

Tags: python

I have a file which, for example, looks like:

```
1  1  5.5
1  2  6.1
1  3  7.3
2  2  3.4
2  3  9.2
3  3  4.7
```

This is "half" of a symmetric 3x3 matrix. I would like to create the full symmetric matrix in Python which looks like

```
[[ 5.5 6.1 7.3] 
 [ 6.1 3.4 9.2]
 [ 7.3 9.2 4.7]]
```

(of course my actual file is a much bigger 'half' of a NxN matrix so I need a solution other than typing in the values one by one)

I've exhausted all my resources (books and internet) and what I have so far does not really come close. Can anyone please help me with this?

Thank you!

Comment: what did you try so far? did you try something to actually read the file and load it into python objects?

Comment: and have a look at [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/)

Comment: Do you know the size of the square matrix in advance?

Answer (score 0):

to read the file and load it as a python object, here's a solution:

```
import numpy

m = numpy.matrix([[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]])

with file('matrix.txt', 'r') as f:
    for l in f:
        try:
            i, j, val = line.split(' ')
            i, j, val = int(i), int(j), float(val)
            m[i-1,j-1] = val
        except:
            print("couldn't load line: {}".format(l))

print m
```

Comment: If it is symmetric and only half is specified in the file, you also want to add `m[j,i] = val`

Comment: Thanks for the input. The code didn't really work for me but after a couple of corrections I got it to work. i had to use m[i-1,j-1] in the loop since i and j start from 1 and should start from 0. Also i used m = numpy.matlib.zeros((N,N)) since I'm working with big NxN matrices. Thanks Again

Comment: FYI, the correct way to say thank you on Stack Overflow, is [to accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) and [up vote it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) when you'll have enough reputation to do it. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative way to do this completely inside Numpy. Two important remarks:

- you can read directly with the `np.loadtxt` function
- you can assign the upper-half values to the correct indexes in one line: `N[idxs[:,0] - 1, idxs[:,1] - 1] = vals`

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np    
from StringIO import StringIO

indata = """
1  1  5.5
1  2  6.1
1  3  7.3
2  2  3.4
2  3  9.2
3  3  4.7
"""

infile = StringIO(indata)

A = np.loadtxt(infile)

# A is
# array([[ 1. ,  1. ,  5.5],
#        [ 1. ,  2. ,  6.1],
#        [ 1. ,  3. ,  7.3],
#        [ 2. ,  2. ,  3.4],
#        [ 2. ,  3. ,  9.2],
#        [ 3. ,  3. ,  4.7]])

idxs = A[:, 0:2].astype(int)
vals = A[:, 2]

## To find out the total size of the triangular matrix, note that there
## are only n * (n + 1) / 2 elements that must be specified (the upper
## half amount for (n^2 - n) / 2, and the diagonal adds n to that).
## Therefore, the length of your data, A.shape[0], must be one solution
## to the quadratic equation: n^2 + 1 - 2 * A.shape[0] = 0
possible_sizes = np.roots([1, 1, -2 * A.shape[0]])

## Let us take only the positive solution to that equation as size of the
## result matrix
size = possible_sizes[possible_sizes > 0]

N = np.zeros([size] * 2)

N[idxs[:,0] - 1, idxs[:,1] - 1] = vals

# N is
# array([[ 5.5,  6.1,  7.3],
#        [ 0. ,  3.4,  9.2],
#        [ 0. ,  0. ,  4.7]])

## Here we could do a one-liner like
# N[idxs[:,1] - 1, idxs[:,0] - 1] = vals

## But how cool is it to add the transpose and subtract the diagonal? :)
M = N + np.transpose(N) - np.diag(np.diag(N))

# M is
# array([[ 5.5,  6.1,  7.3],
#        [ 6.1,  3.4,  9.2],
#        [ 7.3,  9.2,  4.7]])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the size of the matrix in advance (and it sounds like you do), then the following would work (in both Python 2 and 3):

```
N = 3
symmetric = [[None]*N for _ in range(SIZE)]  # pre-allocate output matrix

with open('matrix_data.txt', 'r') as file:
    for i, j, val in (line.split() for line in file if line):
        i, j, val = int(i)-1, int(j)-1, float(val)
        symmetric[i][j] = val
        if symmetric[j][i] is None:
            symmetric[j][i] = val

print(symmetric)  # -> [[5.5, 6.1, 7.3], [6.1, 3.4, 9.2], [7.3, 9.2, 4.7]]
```

If you don't know the size`N`ahead of time, you could preprocess the file and determine the maximum index values given.